# Is there any way to access blender defined vertex group in Godot?

Tags: blender, mesh, vertex, godot, gdscript

I'm trying to automate SoftBody creation in Godot. Everything is working perfect except for the part were I'm supposed to supply pinned points for mesh.

```
var node = SoftBody.new()
node.pinned_points = [] #This is the array where I'm supposed to supply vertex id like: [1, 45, 1142]
```

Those are the vertex points that keep mesh hold position. Now since I'll use script for multiple models I can't use Godot editor for that purpose. So I thought I'll make an additional group in blender vertex group and access those vertices in Godot but I don't know the HOW part. Is there any alternative way? I'm open to ideas. Thanks!

Comment: I don't think that's possible in a script, but you might try a Python script in Blender to list an array you could paste into the engine somewhere. Doesn't sound like a very useable solution I know :)